# Transmit each bit inside a byte

Tags: c

I am a newbie!
I need to pass an array of hex values bit by bit. I am not sure as to how to do it.

let's say I have array defined below,

```
const uint_8t a[] = { 0xAA, 0xF8, 0x03, ... };
int size=sizeof(a) / 8;

//edited

SBIT(port, SFR_P0, 1);

void Data(int *a, int size) {   
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        port = a[i];
    }
}
```

How can I pass this array bit by bit to a function pointing to MSB first.

Comment: you mean you want to pass as binary digits?

Comment: Please show the signature of the function you would like to pass the data to.

Comment: what output do you expect ?

Comment: @Phong I expect port to be set as 101010..... when I pass the array

Comment: Related: [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/45249)

Comment: What is the definition of `SBIT()` ?

Comment: `int *a` does not match the definition `const uint_8t a[]`.

Comment: @chqrlie SBIT is sfr

Comment: @chqrlie I redefined as void data(int a[],...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *pass* bit addresses. But you can enumerate the bits and pass their values with 2 nested loops:

```
const uint_8t a[] = { 0xAA, 0xF8, 0x03, ... };
size_t size = sizeof(a);
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int shift = 8; shift-- > 0; ) {
        transmit_bit((a[i] >> shift) & 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the inner loop should be `for (int shift = 7; shift-- >= 0; )` as otherwise the most significant bit is shifted out in the first iteration.

Comment: @Codor: no, your version omits the most significant bit.  An alternative that requires a signed type would be `for (int shift = 7; shift >= 0; shift--) ...` but I like to emphasize the number of iterations `8`, and using `shift-- > 0` allows an unsigned type to enumerate values from `8-1` to `0` inclusively.

Comment: You're right, I had a misconception on when the `shift--` takes place.

Comment: Thank you. But, by doing a[i]>>shift, I am doing right shift and passing LSB first right?

Comment: @Codor: an alternative that is slightly more readable is `for (int shift = 8; --shift >= 0; )` but it can only be used for signed types.  I use the posted one for most loops with a decrementing counter to avoid having to worry about signedness.

Comment: @sss: no the first bit transmitted is `a[0] >> 7`, the second is `(a[0] >> 6) & 1`...  the bits are transmitted as binary values `0` or `1` from the most significant to the least significant.  If you meant to transmit bytes, that's a different problem.  And if you meant to transmit `0x80` for the most significant bit set, it is easy to change the expression to `transmit_bit((a[i] & (1 << shift));`

Comment: @sss In the shift you describe, it depends an the value of `shift`.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks. Solved my problem

Comment: So, I have edited as port=((a[i]>>shift)&1)      shift I have defined as 8. This is correct I suppose

Comment: @sss: I suppose `port` is supposed to be assigned a value `0` or `1`.  You have a reputation of 21 now.

Answer (score 0):

The individual bits of a single `uint_8t` `arg` can be indexed as follows, where the most significant bit is processed first.

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    uint_8t i_th_bit = ( arg >> i ) & 1;
}
```

You could iterate over `a` and process the bytes bit-wise as above.